# PHP regex start and end with letter or number

Tags: php, regex

I want to match something that start and end with a-z or 0-9 but in the middlle there can be - _

Something like:

```
client-version works
client-version* doesn't work
*client-version doesn't work
```

I can't find the right regex please.

Many thanks

Comment: Try: `^[^\W_][\w-]*[^\W_]*$`

Comment: Almost but i can put _ or - at the end

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following regex pattern:

```
^[^\W_](?:[\w-]*[^\W_])?$
```

Explanation:

```
^                      from the start of the string
    [^\W_]             match a leading word character EXCEPT for underscore
    (?:[\w-]*[^\W_])?  match an optional term containing zero or more word characters plus hyphen
                       ending again in a word character except underscore
$                      end of the string
```

Comment: Ouch!  The punishment for answering a bad regex question!